# bash / cmp: compare two consecutive jpg. files with same size of a long list

Tags: linux, bash, cmp

I'm trying to apply the `cmp` command to a number of consecutive jpg files with same size but different name, in order to make sure they are the indeed same. Since there are almost 4000 files, I would like to create a `for` loop through them with `cmp` and produce a final output with the list of actual same files,  but so far I haven't been able to.

This is a sample of the file list:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1094433 dic 30 09:12 IMG_0199.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1094433 lug 30  2016 img_0199_28043673584_o.jpg  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1124837 dic 30 09:12 IMG_0103.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1124837 lug 30  2016 img_0103_28045527533_o.jpg  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1174143 ago 12  2016 img_1520_28906930111_o.jpg  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1174143 dic 30 12:33 IMG_1520.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1227753 dic 30 09:12 IMG_0104.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 giu_  1227753 lug 30  2016 img_0104_28044608674_o.jpg
```

Comment: Could you add the (non-working) script you already have? Right now it looks a bit like a code assignment, rather than a "please help me with this program?"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be clear in your question, show us sample meaningful Input(s) and meaningful expected output in code tags in your posts.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Have you tested using cmp -l ?

Comment: You should also look at the diff command.

Comment: For real-world use cases, there are 3rd-party programs that are optimized to do this job efficiently -- instead of reinventing the wheel, you'll want to use a tool such as [`jdupes`](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes), [`fdupes`](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes), or similar.

Comment: @Cyclonecode, diff is a bad choice for this job -- it intentionally pays large costs in efficiency to compute a delta. If all you want to know is whether any difference exists, but not what it is, then `cmp -s` (with the argument so it can exit as soon as it finds the first delta) is much more efficient. (Similarly, `cmp -s` can exit without even opening *either* file if it's able to infer that their contents differ from `stat` data).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and valuable input; I tried this in a bash script and he output was none :

cd /directory/;
for i in *.{jpg,JPG}; do \
    cmp -s "$i" "$i";
done;more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a coding exercise (in which case my recommendation is not applicable), look into `fdupes`.  It does exactly what you want.

```
FDUPES(1)                         General Commands Manual                        FDUPES(1)

NAME
       fdupes - finds duplicate files in a given set of directories

SYNOPSIS
       fdupes [ options ] DIRECTORY ...

DESCRIPTION
       Searches the given path for duplicate files. Such files are found by comparing file
       sizes and MD5 signatures, followed by a byte-by-byte comparison.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I did not know about it. With the option --N --noprompt , it automatically deletes all the duplicates preserving just one copy  (to be used with care) Great tool. Thanks

Comment: @Giuseppe - If this answer was helpful and solved your problem you should consider accepting it and perhaps give it an upvote.